# Firebase rule to check if newData value is over a certain amount

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So im adding rules to my firebase realtime database and I need it to check if the newData value being added is over a certain amount, which in this case is the users balance under their uid. So if the users 'balance' is over the 'price' data being added then write the data.

Heres what my database looks like:

```
{
  "orders" : {
   "-Lfi6kSDLOmcvGgfiWjX" : {
        "amount" : "100",
        "price" : "0.01",
      },
  },
  "users" : {
    "GNzSciHRZAgZgIrhqIvR2vzVugj2" : {
      "balance" : "100",
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code im using to add to the database:

```
firebase.database().ref('orders').push().set ({
price: '10',
amount: '1'
});
```

And this is the rules for that:

```
   "users": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
   },

 "orders": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('balance').val() > '0' && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('balance').val() > newData.child('price').val()" 
   }
```

Everything works until i add the `newData.child('price').val()` rule, is this how the rule is used?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing the value as a string, Firebase will use lexicographical ordering and string comparison operators on it. I *highly* recommend storing the numeric values as actual number, which makes the rules a lot simpler to reason about:

JSON:

```
{
  "orders" : {
   "-Lfi6kSDLOmcvGgfiWjX" : {
        "amount" : 100,
        "price" : 0.01,
      },
  },
  "users" : {
    "GNzSciHRZAgZgIrhqIvR2vzVugj2" : {
      "balance" : 100,
    }
  }
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
firebase.database().ref('orders').push().set ({
  price: 10,
  amount: 1
});
```

Rules:

```
"orders": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "
    root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('balance').val() > 0 && 
    root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('balance').val() >= newData.child('price').val()" 
}
```

Note the change from `>` to `>=` in the last expression too, since you probably also want to allow the write when the user has exactly enough money.

---

**Update**

Aside from that, your rules are declared on `orders` itself, where they should be declared one level lower on the specific order.

So:

```
"orders": {
  "$orderId": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "
      root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('balance').val() > 0 && 
      root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('balance').val() >= newData.child('price').val()" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got it working with your suggestions of using numerical values and added the >= but one question. Im getting the data from a html number input (which i should have said at first) so when using jquery to get the data im using `price: $("#price").val()` which saves the data as a string in my database. How can I make it so firebase stores it as a numeric value as you stated I should do.

Comment: For your additional question: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+convert+string+to+number

Comment: I sorted the numeric problem but in fact i have run into another problem, the  `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('balance').val() >= newData.child('price').val()` doesnt seem to work when using `.push().set` it only seems to work when i use `.update`. I get a permission warning when using it with push.set and it doesnt add to the database, as its adding a new child in front of the data do i have to add another `.child()` query? for example when using the push.set it adds the child `-Lfi6kSDLOmcvGgfiWjX`, then the data inside that